# How to find duplicates in SQL Server in one column provided other column the same and third column has not duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is no trivial task.

Here is table:

```
id | project_id | sum_1 | sum_2
```

Task:

- Find all records meet all conditions below:

  1. project_id the same and:
  2. sum_2 has duplicates (with same project_id)
  3. sum_1 has NOT duplicates

List all columns of this selection as result:

```
id | project_id | sum_1 | sum_2
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Please provide some sample data and sample output.  This will help to determine a solution.

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far. We aren't here to do your (home)work.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried do this:

Comment: Sorry, I've tried do this: 

<!-- language: lang-sql --> SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE (sum_2) IN 
 ( SELECT project_id, sum_2 FROM dbo.Table GROUP BY project_id, sum_2 HAVING count(*) > 1)

ORDER BY sum_2

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your (future) database question(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM dbo.YourTable
FROM (  SELECT  project_id,
                sum_2
        FROM dbo.YourTable
        GROUP BY project_id,
                 sum_2
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
        AND COUNT(DISTINCT sum_1) = COUNT(*)) B
    ON A.project_id = B.project_id 
    AND A.sum_2 = B.sum_2;
```

Comment: Many thanks! Final code was:

<code>SELECT A.* FROM dbo.Table A

JOIN (  SELECT  project_id,
                sum_2
        FROM dbo.Table
  WHERE sum_2 > 0
        GROUP BY project_id,
                 sum_2
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
        AND COUNT(DISTINCT sum_1= COUNT(*)) B

    ON A.project_id = B.project_id 

    AND A.sum_2 = B.sum_2; </code>

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.  Also it demonstrates how you can build sample data for your questions.

```
Create Table #Temp (id int, projectid int, sum_1 int, sum_2 int)
Insert #Temp Values (1, 1, 100, 150)
Insert #Temp Values (2, 1, 99, 135)
Insert #Temp Values (3, 1, 80, 150)
Insert #Temp Values (4, 2, 100, 150)
Insert #Temp Values (5, 2, 100, 150)
Insert #Temp Values (6, 3, 100, 150)
Insert #Temp Values (7, 3, 110, 160)
Insert #Temp Values (8, 3, 120, 150)
Insert #Temp Values (9, 4, 100, 180)
Insert #Temp Values (10, 4, 110, 150)
Insert #Temp Values (11, 3, 190, 150)

;With cteCounted As
(
Select Distinct ProjectID 
    From  
        (
        Select  *,
                Count(*) Over (Partition By projectid,sum_1) Sum_1Cnt,
                Count(*) Over (Partition By projectid,sum_2) Sum_2Cnt
            From #Temp
        ) A
    Where Sum_1Cnt = 1 and Sum_2Cnt > 1
)
Select * 
    From #Temp T
    Join cteCounted C On T.projectid = C.projectid  
     Order By ID
```